# Run a method at particular time

Tags: c#, windows-services

I will be having a Dictionary of scheduled Datetimes. If any of the Datetime in the Dictonary is equal to Current Time, i need to call a method. Please tell what i need to do to achieve this. I don't want it to run daily. Only once.

I will be having Dictionary having many records, for sample look at following data:

```
Dictionary<DateTime,int> dic = new Dictionary<DateTime,int>();

Values:
10-03-2017 07:30:01 PM,1
10-03-2017 07:34:01 PM,2
10-03-2017 07:37:05 PM,3
10-03-2017 07:39:55 PM,4
```

This is a sample of values and i will be having like this around 100. When the time reaches current time i need to Call a method in the following format passing the dictionary value. Inside the method i will do processing.

```
ProcessValue(int val)
{

}
```

Comment: Define "Equal to Current Time". What does that mean to you?

Comment: It is ok. What i am trying to ask is whether i have to create a seperate timer for each dictionary key and pass the value on the elapsed time or else is there any other way instead of creating many timers

Comment: If the application is running constantly, a single timer will suffice using a dictionary structure as above. My question was alluding to the fact that a DateTime object has millisecond precision. I'll suggest a solution, however, assuming it's seconds you want.

Comment: Yes John, i will be consider till seconds only. And also i would like to mention one more thing. For easy understanding i have given sample as dictionary, but in realtime i will be having scenario like i will be having duplicate datetimes with different values.

Comment: Is the data in the dictionary dynamic ? can it change from the moment it entered till the the execution?

Comment: Yes, it will keep on changing for every five minutes

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the best solution, but without knowing more about your scenario, I can't give a better option.

As you're aware, a dictionary can't contain duplicate key values, which it sounds like something you require. I've changed it from a dictionary of DateTime -> int, to DateTime -> List because of this.

To find items by seconds, I've implemented a custom equality comparer which will use the ticks to generate a unique hashcode, and perform an equality comparison down to seconds:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<int>> dic = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<int>>(DateSecondEqualityComparer.Instance());

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> values;
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
    if (dic.TryGetValue(currentTime, out values))
    {
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            ProcessValue(value);
        }
        // If you want to remove the date from the dictionary, uncomment the line below
        // dic.Remove(currentTime);
    }
}

private void ProcessValue(int val)
{

}

public class DateSecondEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<DateTime>
{
    public static DateSecondEqualityComparer Instance()
    {
        return new DateSecondEqualityComparer();
    }

    public bool Equals(DateTime x, DateTime y)
    {
        return x.Date == y.Date && x.Hour == y.Hour && x.Minute == y.Minute && x.Second == y.Second;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DateTime obj)
    {
        // ticks -> seconds
        var seconds = (obj.Ticks / 10000000);
        return seconds.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```